# How can I export MIUI notes?

Tags: miui, notes, export, miui-10

I'm using a Xiaomi RedMi 3S phone, whose MIUI environment includes a "Notes" app.

The app itself does not have an export feature. Can I somehow locate/extract the note data - for all notes - into text files, or some other readable format?

Note: I don't know where this data is stored.

Comment: Can you share the apk of this MIUI notes installed in your phone? I would like to investigate if the app data can be backed up using adb or not. FYI, sharing the app is totally harmless from point of view of privacy, so you should not feel reluctance, if any. :-) Try any tool to copy apk and share it. https://play.google.com/store/search?q=apk%20extract%20backup&c=apps&hl=en_US&gl=US // BTW, is your device rooted?

Comment: @Firelord: I never installed my notes app from an APK, it is pre-installed with the phone. Also, I don't have a Google account so there's no use in sending me to the play store. My device is not rooted. I can give you the app information from the Settings menus, if you like...

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean that you installed it from outside. I guess I caused confusion on that part. I just want you to share the apk so that I can look into its manifest. You can try any app backup / extractor app from third-party stores to copy the apk and share it.

Comment: @Firelord, here's my MIUI Notes app apk: https://app.box.com/s/7d4kq8pdlarambxjmjtg1p8gu192zfgq.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it in the following way:

1. Synced notes with Xiaomi Cloud
2. Logged in to Xiaomi Cloud with my browser
3. Intercepted network requests with the help of BurpSuite
4. Parsed JSON-bodies with Python
5. Exported to Excel
6. TODO: Upload to Google Keep

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't want to share my personal data with Xiaomi (that is, assuming they don't already treat themselves to it without my consent).

Answer (score 0):

Choose an option:

1. Simple copy-paste.
2. Share/send note option - whichever exists - thereby sharing (exporting) it to the app (and hence format) you prefer.
3. Screenshot, because that's a readable format too, logically speaking.

Don't know what the version of notes is in your Redmi 3s. Probably very outdated. Otherwise in newer apps, you have a not so good export feature.

Comment: That would need to be done for every note separately. As for the version of notes - it's the same one as in newer Xiaomi phones actually.

Comment: Ow. I never tried batch exporting. I didn't know you were talking about that.

Comment: I thought that was obvious, but - edited to clarify.